# 404 Error only on when requesting WWW domain?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a nodejs server running with nginx as a reverse proxy. `https://example.com` and `http://example.com` run correctly with `http://example.com` redirecting to https, but `http://www.example.com` gives an nginx error `404 Not Found`. `https://www.example.com` does work, though.

This is my server block configuration:

```
server {

        root /var/www/partyshare.shop/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name partyshare.shop www.partyshare.shop;

        location / {
                      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/partyshare.shop/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/partyshare.shop/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = partyshare.shop) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name partyshare.shop www.partyshare.shop;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

I believe the error is on the second server block, where `$host = www.partyshare.shop` when requesting the `http` version, so it skips past the redirect and returns a 404 error. I tried adding an if statement for the www version, but it errored out, and wouldn't recognize my SSL certificate as the http was crossed out in red, so if anybody could help that would be great.

Comment: yes. you are right. the if condition only matches the non-www host and thus returns 404 in the last line.
either dublicate it, or remove the if completely, and just return 301

Answer (score 0):

You should update the 2nd server block to do the same for both `partyshare.shop` and `www.partyshare.shop`, and not just `partyshare.shop`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name partyshare.shop www.partyshare.shop;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```